# Solving homogen and then inhomogen ode system with algebraic multiplicity higher than geometric multiplicity.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need help to solve this problem.

b is real and the ode-system is a system matrix with an algebraic multiplicity = 2 and geometric multiplicity = 1 with eigenvalue 2

$ x_1'(t)=-2x_2(t)+ e^t $

$ x_2'(t)=2x_1(t)+ 4x_2(t)+be^t $

I have then the solution $x(t)= \begin{bmatrix}a\\-a\end{bmatrix} t e^{2t}+\begin{bmatrix}0\\-3\end{bmatrix} e^{2t}$

How do I find the value a and the complete real solution to the homogen system? And the solution to the inhomogene system if $x(t)= \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} e^t $

Comment: Something  weird with the second equation you have two terms $x_2$ on RHS

Comment: you're right, thanks !